# I have enough memory but am getting the INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE error

Tags: android, eclipse

I am working on a game in eclipse. I connect my android phone to test my game application. Upon pressing "RUN" in eclipse, the game will begin to be uploaded to my device. However, it onl makes it half way then the console in eclipse gives me this error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE. I checked my internal storage and I have 30mb left. My game is 3.20mb. I should have plenty of room. shouldn't I? Is this just a bug?

ps. This is very frustrating to me.  I go to google developer forums and they tell me that if I am a neebie, to post on stackoverflow.  I post on stackoverflow only to find they migrate me to SuperUser.  Then SuperUser says, you were supposed to post on Android Enthusiast (beta), and migrate me there.  Finally, I just looked, and someone posted that my question belongs on STACKOVERFLOW!!!  Now I am back where I started. I am just trying to get some answers.  Could someone please help me instead of migrating me please?

Answer (score 0):

My application had a special german character in it,
like

**"ö,ä,ü ... ß"** .... (it was ö), prohibited adb to deploy the apk file no the device.
-> resulted in this error message...

so check your project name.

good luck!